# How to redirect url to another with the hash in the middle of the address

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to redirect that url:

`mydomain.com/folder1/folder2/`

to:

`mydomain.com/#/folder1/folder2`

The thing is, that the `/folder1/folder2/` part of URL I want to read as a parameters so that is why I am using hash for it.

So it should be something like:

`hostdomain.some/different text/another one`

to:

`hostdomain.some/#/different text/another one`

so I can get the `different text/another one`  as a parameters.

I've tried most of the solution given here, but neither helped.

[EDIT] Ok, I think I found a resolution to this.

[Solution](https://gist.github.com/joshmattvander/1640735)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in you root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/.+)$ /#$1 [L,NE,R=302]
```

Change `302` to `301` once it is working.

Comment: Ok, I used it as well with the solution I found myself on github and You syntax works! So great thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /#$1/$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi, thank You for answering. I've tried this one, and it works, but I've got net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS for files with styles for it. Need to figure out how to read them.